# Why weaker overridden functions are not allowed in Java?

Tags: java, access-modifiers

I have the following code:

```
public class Library {

    public void myFunction() {
        // do something
    }
}
public class Book extends Library{

    protected void myFunction() { // Error here
        // do something
    }

}
```

The above code has error because the Book class is trying to override a function of the supper class with a weaker access modifier. I know this is the rule of Java. But I am curious why is that? What the problem it might cause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider, from an entirely different package:

```
new Book().myFunction()             // clearly, no access

((Library)new Book()).myFunction()  // now ... access?
```

The issue really comes down to `myFunction` being *virtual*; the method invoked depends on the *runtime-type* and not the static type of the expression. (I believe C# would actually allow this for a non-virtual method with the `new` modifier.)

Answer (score 0):

Certainly because if some is given a Library then he should be supposed to call `myFunction` as it's Public in it's signature.

So if you return a book like `Library test = getALibraryObject();`, you see the method can't be protected in some object and not others.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is a bit off since a book is not a library. But let's consider Car and Truck.

```
public class Car {
    public start() {}
}

public class Truck extends Car {
    protected start() {}
}

Car c = new Truck(); // should be possible yes?
c.start(); // this is why you cannot change access modifiers in sub classes
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that there's a class `Reader`

```
public class Reader {
  private final Library library;

  public Reader(Library library) {
    this.library = library;
  }

  public void read() {
    library.read();
  }
}
```

that is initialized with an instance of a `Book`:

```
Reader reader = new Reader(new Book());
```

Then, the reader wouldn't be able to read a book, since its `read` method is not visible in the context of a `Reader`. `Reader` can access `Library`'s `read` method, but can not access `Book`'s `read` method, which is quite strange, huh?

Answer (score -1):

it is rule of Object oriented language.
you cant bind the access control of overriden method. 
if overridden method is protected then you can override it as a public but vice versa is not possible

Comment: It is not a rule of 'Object-Oriented Language'. It has nothing to do with OO whatsoever. It is an elementary principle that the originally specified security should not be subvertible.

Comment: what is different between principle and rule??

Comment: As EJP said, it hasn't got anything to do with object-orientation. Also, as pst says, in C# it is possible to do something similar using the "new" keyword. And C# is object-oriented as well.

Comment: The difference isn't between 'principle' and 'rule', the difference is between 'of Object-Oriented Language' and 'elementary principle ... [of] security'. I find this rather obvious frankly, as is the mistake in your original post.